# Password_verify fails for password created on another server

Tags: php, hash, php-password-hash

I recently had to import mysql backup database to another server. My problem is the `password_verify()` function it fails to verify the password when I login. The php version of the both servers is`PHP 7.3.7` and I the algorithm used is `Argon2id`. I´m also using `xampp-windows-x64-7.3.7`, in case this info has any relevance. 
What could be the problem?

Comment: *"This algorithm is only available if PHP has been compiled with Argon2 support."* – Check your `phpinfo()` for starters…

Comment: Do you mean `Compiler` field that appears in `phpinfo()` must be the same always?

Comment: I’m not exactly sure where that info would appear, but somewhere on that long page “argon” should probably be explicitly mentioned. Ctrl+F and search for “argon” on both your servers’ `phpinfo`…

Comment: There isn´t any `argon` word in the whole page with `phpinfo`.

Comment: Well, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.requirements.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.installation.php. This should show up *somewhere*. Or at least it should give you a hint what to look for.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will take a look, but I confess Im a bit lost here.

Comment: As far as I can tell, XAMPP distributes the windows-builds provided by windows.php.net.  There is no libargon2.dll in the zip-file, but libsodium seems to be included -- you can try out if `sodium_crypto_pwhash_str_verify(hash, password)` is available and working -- it uses argon2id per its documentation, you would have a viable workaround. Caveat: I don't know if argon2 would be statically linked under windows, thus could be available without a dll.

Comment: It gives an error. `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sodium_crypto_pwhash_str_verify()`

Comment: From the docs at php.net: "Windows
In order to use this extension you have to add extension=php_sodium.dll to php.ini."

Comment: Nota Bene: php-7.4 will automatically use libsodium to provide argon2i/argon2id if it wasn't build against libargon, but libsodium.

Comment: That means `password_verify()` will work in php 7.4 when importing sql between servers without necessity of install/use sodium?

Comment: Correct. You do not need the sodium functions enabled to use `password_hash` with Argon2. Make sure `PASSWORD_ARGON2ID` is defined on the server unable to process hashes

Comment: @Machavity How can I define `PASSWORD_ARGON2ID`? If I register a user in a server the password works for that server. But if I import that database to the other server the password wont work. The same thing happens in the both servers.

Comment: @SilverSurfer Er, that's a PHP constant. You shouldn't define it. Checking to make sure it's defined should hopefully help narrow down any problems